# Having trouble with 2D animation key framing

Tags: animation, 2d

I have made a monkey head with independent eyes. I would like to be able to rotate the eyes in the sockets, but every time I try to animate them they do bizarre things.

For instance, in the first picture you can see that I have selected the left eye. There is a keyframe at `1` on the timeline. In picture two you can see that I have moved the slider to keyframe `3`, rotated the left eye 30 degrees, and I attempt to insert a new keyframe choosing *Insert Keyframe* and *All Channels*.

A new keyframe appears, but the eye has disappeared, there is the rotated eye on the onion skin indicating that the eye has rotated in frame `1` rather than in frame `3`.

If I go to frame `5` and repeat the process, the eye is still gone and the eye has rotated to 60 degrees in frame `1`.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]